# Get inserted ids after failed insert_many()

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm currently trying to write a script that inserts documents into a MongoDb and returns where each element is stored. Very simple thanks to `insert_many()`, however my problem occurs if there is an error while I'm inserting.

I won't be able to get the ids that have just been inserted.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(...)
db = client.test

r = db.test.insert_many([{'foo': 1}, {'foo': 2}, {'foo': 3}])
r.inserted_ids
#: [ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff8'),
#:  ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff9'),
#:  ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efffa')]

list(db.test.find())
#: [{'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff8'), 'foo': 1},
#:  {'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff9'), 'foo': 2},
#:  {'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efffa'), 'foo': 3}]

# This is dead stupid, but forcing an error by re-using the ObjectId we just generated
r2 = db.test.insert_many([{'foo': 4}, {'_id': r.inserted_ids[0], 'foo': 6}, {'foo': 7}])
#: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#: BulkWriteError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
#: <Cut in the interest of time>
```

Of course, `r2` is not initialized, so I can't ask for `inserted_ids`, however, there will have been one record inserted into the database:

```
list(db.test.find())
#: [{'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff8'), 'foo': 1},
#:  {'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efff9'), 'foo': 2},
#:  {'_id': ObjectId('56b2a592dfcce9001a6efffa'), 'foo': 3},
#:  {'_id': ObjectId('56b2a61cdfcce9001a6efffd'), 'foo': 4}]
```

What I want, is to be able to reliably figure out what Id's were inserted in order. Something Like:

```
r2.inserted_ids
#: [ObjectId('56b2a61cdfcce9001a6efffd'),
#:  None, # or maybe even some specific error for this point.
#:  None]
```

Setting `ordered=False` still gives the error so `r2` won't be initialized, (and it won't reliably return the ids in the order I gave anyway).

Is there any option here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pymongo sets the `_id` field at client side](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#why-does-pymongo-add-an-id-field-to-all-of-my-documents), before sending it to the server. It modifies the documents you pass **in place**.

This means that *all* the documents you pass are left with the `_id` field set -- the successful ones and the failed ones.

So you just need to figure out which ones are successful. This can be done like @Austin explained.

Something like:

```
docs = [{'foo': 1}, {'foo': 2}, {'foo': 3}]
try:
    r = db.test.insert_many(docs)
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as exc:
    inserted_ids = [ doc['_id'] for doc in docs if not is_failed(doc, exc) ]
else:
    inserted_ids = r.inserted_ids
```

`is_failed(doc, exc)` can be implemented by searching `doc` in the list of failed documents in the exception details, as explained by @Austin.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the thrown exception. At least according to [this site](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/), the returned error details includes the bad record. That should enable you to determine the successful records.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, didn't realised I could find some of that information. Though I still think I'm a bit lost: how can I use this to find out the `ObjectId`'s of the elements that were inserted?

Comment: If your insert is *ordered*, the error should indicate the end of the successful inserts. If you find the bad record, the sublist up to but not including that record should be the successful inserts. If the list is *unordered*, according to the page I cited the list of errors contains all the failures, so presumably you can subtract the bad list from the original list and know the inserted records. (Note: I haven't tried this, I'm speculating.)

Comment: Though if the `ObjectId`'s are generated server side, is there any way of knowing the created `id`s, not just knowing what data was successfully submitted?